# What is the difference between Modules and Namespaces in TypeScript/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried to compile the following code in `TypeScript` to `JavaScript`:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    class MyClass {
        public test() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace the keyword `namespace` with `module`, it still generates exactly the same JavaScript code. So what is the difference between a `module` and `namespace` and when should I choose one over another?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md

Answer (score 3):

> So what is the difference between a module and namespace and when should I choose one over another

They are both *exactly the same*. `module` causes confusion with Native JavaScript (e.g ES6 `module`) so they decided to rename it to `namespace`.

In new code prefer to use `namespace`.